# getInputStream gives FileNotFoundException during Http Digest Authentication in Android

Tags: android, api, http-digest

I am trying to send a POST request to a URL that has HTTP Digest authentication.

I am using [this](http://read.pudn.com/downloads73/sourcecode/mobile/j2me/13232/HttpClient/src/com/enterprisej2me/HttpConnections/DigestAuthHandler.java__.htm) for the Digest. I can understand that in this mechanism there are 2 steps. In the first step the client sends a request and the server responses with a challenge. In the second step the client incorporates the challenge in the request and gets the response from the server. That thing is working properly using the above mentioned class.

I had to change HttpConnection to HttpURLConnection to make it work in Android.

Now, I have the DataConnection class which uses the Digest Auth class to get the work done. The class is as below:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.Log;

public class DataConnection {

    private static DataConnection instance = null;
    DigestAuthHandler dah = new DigestAuthHandler("mytestusername",
            "myencryptedtestpassword");

    public static DataConnection getInstance() throws IOException {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new DataConnection();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public HttpURLConnection getHttpConnection(String request_url)
            throws Exception {
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(request_url)
                .openConnection();

        conn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
        conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", System.getProperty("http.agent"));
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept",
                "application/json,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Pragma", "no-cache");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

//      if (Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK) < Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO)
//           System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");


        return conn;
    }

    public String sendPost(String request_url, byte[] data) throws Exception {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        InputStream is = null;
        OutputStream os = null;
        String responseData = "";
        boolean reconnect = true;
        while (reconnect) {
            try {
                connection = getHttpConnection(request_url);
                dah.prepareHeaders(connection,
                        request_url.substring(request_url.indexOf('/', 8)));
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", data.length
                        + "");
                connection.setDoOutput(true); // POST Method.
                connection.connect();               
                if (connection != null) {
                    os = connection.getOutputStream();
                    os.write(data);
                    os.flush();
                    reconnect = dah.processHeaders(connection);
                    int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
                    String responseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();                   

                    is = connection.getInputStream();
                    int responseLength = (int) connection.getContentLength();

                    if (responseLength != -1) {                     
                        byte[] incomingData = new byte[responseLength];
                        is.read(incomingData);
                        responseData = new String(incomingData);
                    } else {
                        ByteArrayOutputStream bytestream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        int ch;
                        while ((ch = is.read()) != -1) {
                            bytestream.write(ch);
                        }
                        responseData = new String(bytestream.toByteArray());
                        bytestream.close();
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                throw exception;
            } finally {
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
                if (os != null) {
                    os.close();
                }
                if (is != null) {
                    is.close();
                }
            }
        }

        try {
            JSONObject responseJson = new JSONObject(responseData);
            Integer status = (Integer) responseJson.get("status");
            int val = status.intValue();
            if (val == 999999) {
                Log.e("Error 99999",
                        "Client application must be upgraded.");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return responseData;
    }
}
```

Here, I get `FileNotFoundException` for the URL during `getInputStream()` method call. I have verified many times that the URL I'm requesting and the credentials for Digest Auth is 100% correct.

Please Help.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The above problem was solved by checking for a blank connection. The problem was that, the connection was blank, but I was trying to call connection.getInputStream() hence it gave error.

Comment: It would be useful for other users if you could post your codesnippet to show, how you checked for a blank connection. I assume that you haven't done it via `if(con == null)`  ;) And could you please mark your Answer as the "correct answer"?